# Access Hbase With Hiveserver2 Error

Tags: hive, hbase, hue

I use hue to execute hive sql `show tables;`  everything is ok.
But executed hive sql `select * from tablea limit 1;` and got the exception:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException:callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68043:
>   row 'log,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at
>   region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=node4,16020,1476410081203,
>   seqNum=0:5:1",
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller:callWithRetries:RpcRetryingCaller.java:159',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture:run:ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:64',
>   '*org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException:Call
>   to node4/192.168.127.1:16020 failed on local exception:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException:
>   Connection to node4/192.168.127.1:16020 is closing. Call id=9,
>   waitTime=1:16:11',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl:wrapException:RpcClientImpl.java:1239',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl:call:RpcClientImpl.java:1210',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient:callBlockingMethod:AbstractRpcClient.java:213',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation:callBlockingMethod:AbstractRpcClient.java:287',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub:scan:ClientProtos.java:32651',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable:openScanner:ScannerCallable.java:372',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable:call:ScannerCallable.java:199',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable:call:ScannerCallable.java:62',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller:callWithoutRetries:RpcRetryingCaller.java:200',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC:call:ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:369',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC:call:ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:343',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller:callWithRetries:RpcRetryingCaller.java:126',
>   '*org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException:Connection
>   to node4/192.168.127.1:16020 is closing. Call id=9, waitTime=1:3:2',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection:cleanupCalls:RpcClientImpl.java:1037',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection:close:RpcClientImpl.java:844',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection:run:RpcClientImpl.java:572'],
>   statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)

Comment: 'tablea' is correct? Or you just mistyped it in the question?

Comment: 'tablea' is correct . i can get the right result when i  use hive shell to  execute this hiveSQL

Comment: same issue . have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

in the configuration file hive-site.xml

```
<property>  
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>  
    <value>false</value>  
</property>
set the value to false.
```

the true means execute the hadoop job with the user who loginin the hiveserver2.

the false means execute the hadoop job with the user who start the hiveserver2.